# How to substring based on symbol in ADF

Tags: substring, azure-data-factory

I have data like this.. where i would like to remove the data between [] and the symbol. I tried to do the substring based on position, but my string is having different length.

This is I need to do in ADF.

Input : Vloerbedekking specifiek [28]
Output: Vloerbedekking specifiek

Input: Fournituren [45]
Output: Fournituren

Input: Seizoensverlichting [53]
Output: Seizoensverlichting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do a `regexReplace` in your dataflow derive column activity.

The expression used is `regexReplace(INPUT, '\\s+(\\[.*\\])', '')`

The regex's explanation:

- `\\s+`: specifiy 1 or more space
- `(\\[.*\\])`: look for square brackets and words inside

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create dataflow.

[image]

Select derived column.

Use `replace(Name,dropLeft(Name,length(Name)-4))` expression

[image]

Expected output

[image]